# How do I delete the Conversation History folder on Office 365?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, skype-for-business-online

I'd like to know how do I delete the Conversation History folder on an Office 365 account?

I do not use Skype for Business, do not even use Outlook (I access the account for macOS Mail) and the folder is empty. Yet, I can't delete it from the web (the option is just greyed out) and on Mac it gives me the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (MCMailErrorDomain error 1030.)
>   The server returned the error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (MFEWSErrorDomain error 46.)

Does anyone know of a solution or a hack (using Powershell, etc) to delete or hide that useless folder for good? I have admin access on the account if that matters. I've searched around a little bit but most "solutions" I found are completely irrelevant.

Regards.

Comment: It isn't possible to delete it. If you don't use it, why does it bother you so much?

Comment: Fully agree here - why have pointless folders appear? There is already so much screen clutter in outlook, why add some more.

Comment: @joeqwerty even its a old question, the reason for example could be a data protection rule that applies to users. either disable or delete will be told to you so what's the solution

Answer (score 2):

By default, Exchange Online is Integrated with SFB Online, so you cannot delete this folder.

Comment: Can the folder be hidden?